# Static Assert inside struct allowed?

Tags: c++, static-assert

I have several template settings struct, is it ok, to use static asserts in these structs?

```
template<typename T, int N, (and so on...)>
struct Settings{
  static const int n = N;
  STATIC_ASSERT(n == 5);
  typedef typename T GAGA;
}
```

Thanks for your responses!

Comment: this example doesn't make sense.. if n has to be 5, why do you have a template parameter?

Comment: Why don't you compile and see?

Comment: This example is only for demonstration purposes... I just wanted to get some feedback, if this kind of checking template Parameters is a good one... And it seems its fine, as long as the right static assert macro is used, which can be used there! :-)

Comment: Nevertheless, you should accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to look at the `STATIC_ASSERT` macro definition to see what is exactly going on. A common implementation of `STATIC_ASSERT` that can be used there could be:

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT( x ) \
   typedef char static_assert_failed[ (x) ? 1 : -1 ]
```

Usually there is a bit more trickery to get the line number to be part of the typedef so that more than one `STATIC_ASSERT` can be used in the same context, but you can see that this is allowed as it will expand to valid code in the struct definition:

```
template<typename T, int N, (and so on...)>
struct Settings{
  static const int n = N;
  typedef char static_assert_failed[ (n == 5) ? 1 : -1 ];
  typedef typename T GAGA;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what your STATIC_ASSERT is but if you write it using c++11 style static_assert then this works fine and seems like a perfectly good use for static assert. (Well, perhaps not checking it's 5 but checking template parameters are suitable for instantating)

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct Settings {   
  static const int n = N;   
  static_assert(n == 5, "Error");   
  typedef typename T GAGA; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T, int N>
struct Settings
{  
STATIC_ASSERT(N == 5);  
typedef typename T GAGA;
};
```

I dont see a valid reason to use `n`.